# Is it possible for two Codenameone Apps to share a single SQLite database?

Tags: codenameone

IS it possible to have two separate codenameone apps sharing one SQLite database? How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Well, maybe depending on your target platform.

SQLite resides in a filesystem location. Normally app file system access is segregated between apps which means app X can't change/steal the data of app Y.

You can store some files in shared space (historically SD card on Android but there's still a shared space). The problem is only one app can write to it... There are ways to share data between apps but they revolve around copying the data dynamically or passing small bits. Not the full database.

Most people use a server approach. You could theoretically have one app with the database and the other app will query the first app for data. It's possible but super painful to do across platforms.

So generally the answer is you can do something very hacky in theory but it would be very painful.